# Set wallpaper from external storage

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

So I've got my image gallery project all set up with images saved online and not within the application. It works great. But what I want to do is get the facility to set the image as a wallpaper.

I've got the image to download and save in the external storage as `packagename.jpg`

Everywhere I've searched for examples on how to set the wallpaper all seem to be based on the image being within the application.

Anyone have any pointers on how to use wallpapermanger to set an image from external storage as the wallpaper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first retrieve the file from the SDCard and decode the image into a Bitmap using `BitmapFactory` then you can set the bitmap using `WallpaperManager`'s `setBitmap()` method.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/directory/yourimage.jpg");

WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());          

Bitmap myBitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

wallpaperManager.setBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: Spot on mate! I was nearly there just didn't have this line in
Bitmap myBitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
Cheers!